# CucumberJS / Protractor with the angular CLI

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli, e2e-testing, cucumberjs

The lack of documentation for setting Cucumberjs support with the new angular is pretty upsetting.. I am wondering how we can set up cucumber instead of just plain protractor, so that way when we run our tests using the ng e2e command, it picks up feature files.

I am wondering if anyone has any experience setting this up since the introduction of typescript has changed the framework completely.. Has anyone had any success in this? I would essentially like to see an example of setting up the conf files and creating step definitions and page objects. Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks guys

Comment: Have you tried this link yet (https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-protractor-and-cucumber), it looks like my current setup

Comment: @Nugenrules, thank you for the reply. I have not gone through these steps since I do not think that this is for the new angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on a Angular 2+ project with Angular Seed, but that won't differ much from the setup for Angular CLI.

I'm using this [boilerplate](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate) I've created for my customer that has:

- Typescript
- CucumberJS 2 support
- reporting

There is no example for a pageobject in it, but that's not much different from the "old" setup and secondly the boilerplate is just for the basic e2e setup, not for a complete coding guide ;-).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was actually able to get something working using the following example - https://github.com/orieken/cucumber-tsflow-example. Worst part about this so far is that intellij does not support auto detecting step definitions written in TypeScript just yet